Value of $g(2+i)$ given some conditions
Problem. Suppose that  $g$ is analytic in  $B(0:5)$ and for all  $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
\frac{3n^2 -3}{n^2 + (n^2-1)i^{n}}g\left( \frac{n^2}{n^2-1} + i^{n} \right) = 2
$$
What is $g(2+i)$? Justify your answer. Give an additional condition under which $g(3-4i)$ can be determined, and $g(4-4i)$ can be determined. Explain your answer
Attempt. My first step was to determine whether $\frac{n^2}{n^2-1} + i^{n} \in B(0:5)$. As $n \to \infty$, I've deduced that this expression oscillates from $0,2,1-i,1+i$. Also, $\frac{3n^2 -3}{n^2 + (n^2-1)i^{n}}$ is bounded above by either $\frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{1+i}, \frac{3}{1-i}$ as $n \to \infty$. Does this mean $g$ is a constant function? I couldn't seem to combine the conditions since it appears that the value of $g$ depends on $n$. My hunch that $g$ is a constant function is from that fact that $\frac{n^2}{n^2-1} + i^{n} \ne 2+i$ for all $n$.
Can someone help put me in the right direction? Thank you!

Rewrite the identity in the form
$$
g(\frac{n^2+[n^2-1]i^n}{n^2-1})=\frac23\cdot \frac{n^2+[n^2-1]i^n}{n^2-1}.
$$
We see that the identity
$$
g(z)=\frac{2z}3
$$
holds for infinitely many complex numbers $z=z_n$ with accumulation points in an open set where the function is known to be holomorphic. Certain uniqueness result kicks in.
Leaving it to you to figure out what extra is needed for us to be able to extend the identity to the given numbers $3-4i$ and $4-4i$.

I don't frequent [tag:complex-analysis], so i don't know how likely we have duplicates for this. Probably somewhat likely, but I could not find a suitable one.

I got it now. Thanks!
